# c/c++ language server unable to start(and intellisense too) showing spawn unknown system error -86 on my m1 macbook

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I install the C/C++ extension(by Microsoft) on my M1 Macbook after installing Visual Studio Code for the first time,

As soon as I create a cpp file, I get this error:

```
[Error - 10:26:19 AM] Starting client failed

Error: spawn Unknown system error -86

    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:407:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:557:9)
    at /Users/akshay/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.2.2/dist/main.js:15519:40
```

[image: this the screenshot]

I'm using the M1 Macbook and clang works properly(it can compile the program)
but Intellisense does not work (I downloaded previous version of c/c++ extension too , it has the same problem)